# import css file on demand, and remove it when it is not in use

Tags: css, reactjs

I want to import a style sheet when I need it in one context, and remove the style sheet when I am in another context. Is there a way to do this?

I have tried this already, but it seems like the import is not removed even though the component is removed:

```
// Component A file

import "./context-a.css"

const CompontentA = () => <></>




// Component B file

import "./context-b.css"

const CompontentB = () => <></>



// Component that decides if it is component A or B

const ComponentC = () => {
  return isComponentA ? <ComponentA /> : <ComponentB />
}
```

Thanks for all suggestions!